# Italics or quotes in reporting a Voicemail message in a fiction novel

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

In a work of fiction, I have quoted a Voicemail message received. Should that message be in italics, and if so, with or without quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Italics and quotes mean the same thing. Use one or the other, not both. Either is acceptable.

Comment: I believe I did answer the question of the OP should use quotes with italics. And I said no, both shouldn't be used at the same time for the same reason.